# How can I measure the disk space growth rate of a Mercurial repository?

Tags: mercurial

I think our repo is growing too fast because of some binary files that are tracked by mercurial. Can I get some kind of statistics like the rate of growth by day, or by week?

One of my tries was exporting the changesets of a day to a folder and check the size, but that's very laborious, isn't there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just clone your repository as a certain revision (e.g. `-r 10`) and then pull incrementally (i.e. `-r 20`, `-r 30`, etc.).  Measure the disk usage of your cloned repo after each step and you can see how it has grown.

This will give you a pretty rough estimate.  You can refine it to be more accurate to give you growth per day, week, or whatever by doing an `hg log -d` in the original repo to get the specific revisions.

Comment: Actually I did think about that, but my laziness was hopping to find something less manual :P. But the `hg log -d` will be really handy, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way would be to just track the total size of the .hg/store directory over time. You might want to do all of .hg, but depending on your extensions you may well have things in there that aren't really part of "the repository" (for example, hg-git will put an entire bare git repository in .hg/git).

Comment: The problem with this is that it will take too long. The repo was created some weeks ago and I'd like to look at this history, in order to get a more immediate answer. If I start to track the growth from now on, it will take some more weeks.

Comment: Do you back up your repository daily?  If so, you can look at the backup sizes.  If not, then you're a bit stuck for options.